# AWK: How can one determine the shell to be used in awk's the system() command?

Tags: bash, awk

How is it possible to specify the shell to be used which is called when
applying the 'system()' command in awk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`system("command")` is going to run `/bin/sh -c 'command'`.

In GNU awk, [the implementation](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gawk.git/tree/builtin.c) contains a call to the [C `system` function](https://linux.die.net/man/3/system), which uses `/bin/sh`.

You could change what this points to (note that this would have a system-wide effect).

Alternatively, you could use this syntax, as suggested in the [GNU awk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/I_002fO-Functions.html):

```
print "command" | "/path/to/other/shell"
# when you're finished
close("/path/to/other/shell")
```